# How to retrieve all users with and without posts?

Tags: laravel, view, model, controller

I'm setting up a new view to show all usernames with their title post for the admin page. I have 4 user that 2 of them (admin and david) has submitted post and 2 of them has no post so i just could make the below image in output and you can see i have not 2 user with no post so how can i have them inside the below image and in title column have "no post" for that users with no post

**Current Output**
[image]

**View/Blade**

```php
@if ( $user->role_id === '1')
    @foreach ($allposts as $post)
        <tr>
            <th class="font-parsibit">{{ $post->title }}</th>
            <th class="font-parsibit">{{ $post->user->name }}</th>
            <th class="text-center">
                <a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}" class="btn btn-success text-light">Display</a>
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                {!! Form::open(['action' => ['PostsController@destroy', $post->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'mx-auto']) !!}
                {!! Form::hidden('_method','DELETE') !!}
                {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class'=>'btn text-light btn-danger']) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
                <a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}/edit/{{ $post->noo }}" class="btn btn-primary text-light">Edit</a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

**Controller**

```php
public function index()
{
    $allposts = Post::with('user')->get();
    $bgvar = 'dashboard';

    return view('dashboard', compact('bgvar'), compact('allposts'));
}
```

The above code works correctly but as I said to show the username who submitted a post with their title. I expect the output to show me all users with their title posts including users with submitted posts and without. For users that didn't submit any posts I want to show "No Posts" in the title column.

Comment: If you want to show all users, even if they don't have a post, you should be pulling Users, not posts. Then you can populate your view with $user->post

Comment: if you see the picture i attached : for example david is a user with 3 post so if i send all user to view i can't make something like the picture ,,, please explain me with complete answer thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a right join will get all users, including those that don't have any posts, so it's possible for a post to have NULL id:

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $allPosts = Post::selectRaw("posts.id, users.name as user_name, CASE WHEN posts.id IS NULL THEN 'No Post' ELSE posts.title END AS title")
    ->rightJoin('users', 'posts.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('users.role_id', 1)
    ->get();

    return view('dashboard', compact('bgvar'), compact('allPost'));
}
```

**View**

```
@foreach ($allPosts as $post)
    <tr>
        <th class="font-parsibit">{{ $post->title }}</th>
        <th class="font-parsibit">{{ $post->user_name }}</th>
        <th class="text-center">
        @if($post->id)
            <a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}" class="btn btn-success text-light">Display</a>
        @endif       
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
        @if($post->id)
            {!! Form::open(['action' => ['PostsController@destroy', $post->id], 'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'mx-auto']) !!}
            {!! Form::hidden('_method','DELETE') !!}
            {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class'=>'btn text-light btn-danger']) !!}
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        @endif
        </th>
        <th class="text-center">
        @if($post->id)
            <a href="/posts/{{ $post->id }}/edit/{{ $post->noo }}" class="btn btn-primary text-light">Edit</a>
        @endif  
        </th>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: it's not possible we have post but we have no id !  also what is username ? i don't have username in my database post table

Comment: I have updated my answer to include both view and controller. Hoping that will answer your question.